# How did humans grow plants on the Moon despite the harsh conditions?

Tags: the-moon, life, life-support, chang-e

The Chang'e 4 lander contains seeds to grow plants on the Moon. The Moon has non-sustainable life conditions. Among those are the lack of water, atmosphere, the varying extreme temperatures, the low gravity, the solar radiations, etc.

However at least one cotton plant has germed and is in the process of growing.

How did the CNSA engineers have the plants germ then grow on the Moon? And are the plants supposed to die of natural death or will the harsh conditions kill them, if such, which one first?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

While it's still cool, it's not as tricky as it may sound at first:

The seeds, including water, are stored in a sealed, heated and shielded container. The container also includes fruit flies and yeast. So the plants are not grown in the lunar soil (which would be the interesting and challenging next step) but in a portable, sealed ecosystem.

(See for example [this article](https://www.extremetech.com/extreme/283850-first-plants-sprout-on-moon-aboard-change-4-lander), among many about this subject.)

Comment: There is no soil on the moon. Lunar regolith has no organic components, which is the defining characteristic of a soil. Lunar regolith is only ground up rock: silica, iron, aluminium, and oxygen.

Comment: Tangentially, c.f. _The Martian_, and the process of making Mars "dirt" into something capable of supporting plant growth.

Comment: The cotton seedling that sprouted has reportedly been killed by the cold now.

Comment: @Robyn they probably turned off the heating and lights in the growing chamber the moment they had their publicity shots, in order to preserve the batteries of the lander during the lunar night.

Comment: But they're all going to die right? There's no return mission? What are we learning from that other than visually?

Comment: @Mazura [They're already dead](https://www.abc.net.au/news/2019-01-17/change-probe-china-cotton-seeds-moon-dies/10723336).

Comment: I thought I read somewhere the experiment overheated, so there was no point keeping it going through the night. Can't remember where though.